# Distance to the next gap ( datetime column ) in Panda's dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Haven't used Pandas much , decided to give it a try. but can't overcome one problem and make it work efficiently and hope someone could help and guide me

Given a DataFrame with just 2 columns : datetime(minute is the grain) of an event and Sales number.
there are could be gaps , for example

```
Datetime             Value
2001-01-02 04:21:00  1    
2001-01-02 04:22:00  3   
2001-01-02 04:27:00  2  
2001-01-02 04:28:00  2
```

you can see there is a gap between 2001-01-02 04:22:00 and 2001-01-02 04:27:00

I'm looking to calculate distance to the closest gap for each row in the dataframe. in other words I'm looking to get how many minutes left until the next gap in the data
So basically I want to get something like this as the output :

```
Datetime             Value  NextGapIn
2001-01-02 04:21:00  1      1
2001-01-02 04:22:00  3      0
2001-01-02 04:27:00  2      10
2001-01-02 04:28:00  2      9
....
2001-01-02 04:37:00  3      0
2001-01-02 04:40:00
```

I created another dataframe based on the original to store rows where gap happened 
df_gaps = df[(df['DateTime']-df['DateTime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[m]')>1]

but I don't know what next steps should be
I would appreciate any ideas and guidance

Comment: is the gap supposed to be minutes ?

Comment: @Datanovice yes the gap is supposed to be in minutes

Comment: then you can use `df['Datetime'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1,'m')` there are quite a few dupes of this question so that answers your question i'll vote to close it

Comment: @Datanovice it will calculate only difference between current and next element in minutes . but I'm looking to get how many minutes left until the next gap in the data

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by myself. Not sure if it's the efficient way but it works and pretty fast

```
df_gaps = df[(df['DateTime']-df['DateTime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[m]')>1]
df_gaps = df_gaps.set_index('DateTime')

start_time = process_time()

def get_next_gap_lenght (dt):
    s=np.searchsorted(df_gaps.index,dt)
    try:
        val=df_gaps.index[s]
        next_gap_in = int((val - dt).total_seconds()/60)-1
    except:
        next_gap_in=-1
    return next_gap_in

df['NextGapIn'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_next_gap_lenght(x['DateTime']),axis=1)

print(process_time() - start_time)
```